# Google Earth - zoom like with a scope, rotate the camera

Tags: camera, rotate, zoom, google-earth

I know it is possible to change a viewing altitude in Google Earth, but is it possible to zoom in/out as well, like with a telescope?

I would like to preview what could be viewed from a particular lookout point, but without zoom in it seems very hard.

Rotating view around the camera, not around the target, is also handy for the purpose - hold Ctrl and rotate around with a mouse, see [the guide](http://earth.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=22358&topic=22362) - but zoom in/out simply does not seem to be there. When using keys + and - with Control pressed they do nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right clicking and then moving the mouse centres the "zoom" on the location you click rather than the centre of the screen. It still moves the camera though rather than changing the field of view.

There doesn't seem to be a way of changing the camera field of view which is what you need to get zooming without actually moving.

The only solution appears to be to use a Photo Overlay.

[Source](http://groups.google.com/group/kml-support-advanced/browse_thread/thread/6155190fdc087e10?pli=1) - Google Groups, requires an account so see.

Comment: Once I have the photo overlay set up and am viewing it (so I see the perspective I need) how do "Exit Photo" without the camera moving?