# Using Google Earth to identify street addresses while zoomed

Tags: zoom, google-earth

I've got a panoramic image of a city and I'm trying to identify street addresses of houses in the image.  I'm trying to use Google Earth to do this, by first creating a placemark where the image was taken, editing the view height to 0 (relative), and then creating an transparent photo overlay so I can zoom in on the city from that point.  I'm using [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/123066/google-earth-zoom-like-with-a-scope-rotate-the-camera) as a guide.

So far I have succeeded in zooming in on a region containing houses for identification.  However, in order to do this I have "entered" the photo, i.e. there is a button in the upper right which says "Exit Photo".  I am not seemingly able to do anything in this mode other than to tweak my location by panning and altering the zoom.   But if I click "Exit Photo" it returns me to my starting location.  I need instead to be able to explore the area in the photo area.  Ideally it would work like Google Maps and I could just right click or something on the house in question and it would bring up info, but Google Earth does not seem to have this feature.  Instead, I need to somehow break out of photo view without changing the perspective so I can use some other means to select and get info on houses in the view.

How can I do this?

Comment: It sounds as though you need to be using Google Maps to do this, as you note. Also, Google Earth has probably chosen not to provide full address information on purpose as that is not really the purpose of the application, and it duplicates the capabilities of Google Maps.

Comment: @music2myear Google Maps has its own issues, for instance, I haven't even figured out a way to zoom from a given location or even to stand "on the ground" to do so.

Comment: Google StreetView does this, provided it's available in your country. It provides an approximate street address, but you need to verify this by zooming in on house numbers, if you can.

Comment: @AFH Is there some way to switch into StreetView mode without losing my position on the map as fixed by the photo overlay?

Comment: Not as such, but you can tag the location by left-clicking before you enter StreetView. Note that some of the photo images are actually StreetView links.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be somewhat of a hack and hopefully it will continue to work in the future.  I am using Google Earth Pro v 7.3.1 and will make sure I keep this version available in case a future version "fixes" this hack and leaves me with no way to accomplish the task.

First, I right click on the photo overlay name in the sidebar, and select "Get Info" to bring up a dialog box showing info about the overlay.  Now with the dialog up, it seems to be possible to alter the angle at which things are viewed, as if the photo overlay almost wasn't there.   For instance, I can click shift+drag on a house to view the house at an orthogonal angle different from the photo overlay angle, at which point I can then drag the photo overlay completely out of the picture.  Some caution is needed in this process, as sometimes if I click in a sensitive spot the camera angle changes radically with very little control input and I have to reset to the image overlay and try again.

Next, I click "cancel" on the overlay dialog box.  Now I can interact directly with the map, either to go into street view mode, or what seems to be better is to Edit -> Copy View Location, which I can then paste (latitude/longitude) into Google Maps from which point I can click to get the street address.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps has excellent 3D (aerial) maps for some cities, if your browser & video card are supported (firefox may work when chromium doesn't fyi). You could get almost any perspective & rooftop or higher angle (currently with ctrl+mouse and zooming/wheel/+-).

It sounds like using google Maps directly, with a separate window to see the reference city image, might be easier / faster.

For example, if you took a photo from the [Lion's Gate Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions_Gate_Bridge) in [Vancouver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vancouver), BC, Canada, Google Maps has a movable 3D image that you can line up with your photo, something like this:

[image: Lions Gate Bridge]

Then you can scroll over to the big buildings, and if there's a business there that's on Google Maps you'll even get a popup with it's name like this:

[image]

If it's the tallest building that has a bunch of businesses that overlap each other, you can even go to the street view to read the "main" sign on the side of the building itself (Looks like the [Shangri-La Hotel](http://www.shangri-la.com/vancouver/shangrila/)):

[image]